# php sessions and mobile applications

Tags: php, session, mobile

I'm developing application that would communicate with a mobile app. My problem is as follows - my mobile app doesn't accept any session data - no $_GET variables, no cookies - all communication in both sides is done with xml and I can't change it by, for example adding some parameters to xml, because mobile app would not understand those. Now, I would like to use php sessions - mobile app sends me a unique identifier which I can use as a session key. Will this work in an usual manner, like setting some variable in $_SESSION array, and then retrieving them in next request?

ps. I can't use database nor files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `session_id()` function to fetch the PHP session ID and somehow include that in the XML you send to the device, and then at the other end you can extract the unique identifier, call `session_id({unique_parameter});` to set the session ID and then call `session_start();` and you should be all set.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can send this id to my mobile app, and actually - I'm doing it for other that using php session purpose, so that is not a problem - I was just wondering whether I have to send some other data (which php sends by default when working with web browser) back and forth, so that my server would understand that it's the same session, or will it suffice to send just this id? You say it will, but before accepting your answer, I'll wait a bit - maybe someone will tell me that it won't work, and explain why :).

Comment: Rest assured, it will work (provided you call `session_id('the_id');` before `session_start();`.